# SQL Query not consistent across different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables.

1. Team name, Team win ratio, Team location.
2. Team name, Team win ratio, Team location, Team value, Team fan count.
3. Team name, Player name, Player salary.

| Table 1 | Table 2 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team name | Team name | Team name |
| Team win ratio | Team win ratio |  |
| Team location | Team location |  |
|  | Team value |  |
|  | Team fan count |  |
|  |  | Player name |
|  |  | Player salary |

I need to combine 2 tables out of the 3:

- either Table 1 combine Table 3 based on same primary key Team name, or
- Table 2 join Table 3 based on same primary key Team name.

When I combine table 1 and 3 by team name, the join works perfectly, resulting in results with columns: Team name, Team win ratio, Team location, Player name, Player salary. However, when doing table 2 and 3, I get no results, despite table 2 and table 1 being virtually the same thing.

I tried checking to see if Team name in table 1 and Team name in table 2 are the same by doing:

```
SELECT TABLE1.TEAMNAME, TABLE2.TEAMNAME 
FROM TABLE1 
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.TEAMNAME = TABLE2.TEAMNAME
```

Or something along those lines, and I get the table with columns: table1teamname and table2teamname side by side with no issues, and they are exactly the same. However, when I do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT TABLE2.TEAMNAME, TABLE3.TEAMNAME 
FROM TABLE2 
JOIN TABLE3 ON UPPER(TABLE3.TEAMNAME) LIKE ('%'||UPPER(TABLE2.TEAMNAME)||'%')
```

I get no results, whereas if trying something like:

```
SELECT TABLE1.TEAMNAME, TABLE3.TEAMNAME 
FROM TABLE1 
JOIN TABLE3 ON UPPER(TABLE3.TEAMNAME) LIKE ('%'||UPPER(TABLE1.TEAMNAME)||'%')
```

It works completely fine, and I get the two columns table2.teamname and table 3.teamname that are all similar (team name in table 3 is a longer version and capitalised) side by side but matching exactly.

Why would this issue occur? Table 1 and Table 2 are basically the same other than the addition of a couple columns in the table, with the same results, but one table having a little more columns per row.

So to recap, table 1 and 2 are exactly the same, but table 1 fuzzy match on team name with table 3 works and gives rows of data, whereas table 2 fuzzy match with table 3 gives no rows with no matched data. Why is this?

Comment: Please share output of `SHOW CREATE TABLEx\G` for all three tables. (replace `x` with `1`,`2` or `3`).

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Comment: It seems Table 3's team name has a degree of variance giving you unpredictable results.  I second Gordon's request to see the data.

Comment: Check LENGTH(teamname) for the cases of interest.  If you notice the name length differs, but the equals comparison matches, you probably have trailing space padding that is driving the behavior, by design.  This space padding isn't handled the same way in the LIKE clause.  Notice my answer below, which contains a test case, reproducing the behavior.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I solved the problem and this is why stack overflow rocks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is unexpected space padding.  Check out the following:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    id   int
  , name varchar(20)
) charset=UTF8;

INSERT INTO names VALUES
     (1, 'name1')
   , (2, 'name1 ')
   , (3, 'name2')
;

SELECT names.*
     , 'name1' = names.name
     , 'name1' LIKE CONCAT('%', names.name, '%')
  FROM names
;
```

Result:

```
+------+--------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| id   | name   | 'name1' = names.name | 'name1' LIKE CONCAT('%', names.name, '%') |
+------+--------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|    1 | name1  |                    1 |                                         1 |
|    2 | name1  |                    1 |                                         0 |
|    3 | name2  |                    0 |                                         0 |
+------+--------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

[Full test case here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=951ba8955f410fa96b58bd8c456a28cb)

The extra trailing space pad on the name in row with id = 2 causes the equals comparison to match, but the LIKE comparison does not!

This behavior is supported by the SQL Standard for certain collations.  See `<character set specification>` and "PAD SPACE characteristic".

Updated:

```
SELECT names.*
     , 'name1' = names.name
     , 'name1' LIKE CONCAT('%', names.name, '%')
     , 'name1' LIKE names.name
  FROM names
;

+------+--------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| id   | name   | 'name1' = names.name | 'name1' LIKE CONCAT('%', names.name, '%') | 'name1' LIKE names.name |
+------+--------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|    1 | name1  |                    1 |                                         1 |                       1 |
|    2 | name1  |                    1 |                                         0 |                       0 |
|    3 | name2  |                    0 |                                         0 |                       0 |
+------+--------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

[Updated test case here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33f42ca06693b78bef7a84ede8f21351)